Which user's app crashed in the Windows Event Logs?
I have an app that is crashing and leaving crash reports in the Windows Event Logs. They look something like this:

Is it possible to determine which user was running the app when it crashed? If not from the details above, perhaps by flipping some registry setting to enable logging of usernames?

You can do this with Windows Logs -> Security, Task Category = Process Creation
This event from windows logs seems useful: event 4688. It looks like this event tracks process creation incl. account name of the user. This obviously requires that the process is started by the user (not the system). According to this question the event can be enabled via Group Policy. It works by default for me but only logs a very limited amount of process creations. It still might be that the process you are looking for is not recorded.
User Login logging
Otherwise, according to this it is possible to enable user login (and logout) logging using group policies.
The device which I am using to type this is a Windows Home installation and does not have access to group policy manager but it seems that logging is already enabled.
You can see the logged events in the event viewer in Windows-Protocols>Security. There you have to select the time before the point that interests you and go back into the past until you find a useful event.
I think that it (one of the useful event types) is called "Logon" (event 4624). In the Field "Account name" it shows the user account name. You should be aware that there might be many of this type of event so it might require some patience.
